# Counting duplicates with distinct clause

Tags: mysql

I have a query which counts records with duplicate titles (> 1) but I want it only to include results where `status` column is distinct. For example, if two videos have same title and same status (ie. status=2 for both), it should only be counted once. If there are 3 videos with two of the records containing the same status, the count should be 2.

This is my query so far...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`,`title` FROM `videos` GROUP BY `title` HAVING `count`>1;
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `count` with `distinct` instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(distinct status) AS `count`,`title` 
FROM `videos` 
GROUP BY `title` 
HAVING `count`>1;
```

Answer (score -1):

try ...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT status) AS `count`,`title` FROM `videos` GROUP BY `title` HAVING `count`>1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: In addition, it's generally frowned upon posting an answer that was already posted 4-5 minutes before.  This is the exact same solution I already provided . . .

Comment: @sgeddes, my apologies mate, when i read this question initially, there was no answer given. And when I came back after trying out a solution on SQL Studio, there still was no answer (page refresh ?). I'll keep an eye on that in future and thanks for the heads up. Good answer by the way !!!

Comment: @FrankerZ - I'll answer the questions as I see fit and leave it to the person asking the question to decide on it's suitability, if you don't like it, don't read it ...

Comment: @PólO'Muilleoir It's kinda hard to not read it when it ends up in the [Very Low Quality Post Review Queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)